# What will be the next weapon of Thor?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

After Thor's Hammer being crushed by the First Born child of Odin, Hela, what weapon will he be using in the Avengers: Infinity Wars?

In Ragnarok, Thor has gained and lost some things. He lost his supernatural Hammer and one eye to his sister and gained a lot of power as seen in the movie. The lightning in his eyes.

What will be his next weapon a sword or an axe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Signs point to Thor wielding an axe, likely Jarnbjorn or Stormbreaker.

In the comics, [Jarnbjorn](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Jarnbjorn) is the axe wielded by Thor before he received Mjolnir. Later, when he became unworthy of Mjolnir, he once again picked up Jarnbjorn.

[image: Jarnborn]

Right now, our best evidence of this comes in two images.

The first is a shot from the first *Infinity War* trailer.

Thor appears to be attempting to get some sort of large machine moving/activated. The prevailing theory is that it is a star forge used to create the axe.

[image: Star Forge?]

The second is from [a leaked photo](https://twitter.com/RinconMarvels/status/946315971618160640) of one of the upcoming Lego playsets. The playset is called "The Search For Thor's Weapon", and includes Thor and an unidentified* axe.

<sub>*The tweet identifies it as Jarnbjorn, but offers no concrete evidence that it is.</sub>

[image: lego my leak]

A new leaked image has emerged, purportedly showing a playset version of the hammer called "Stormbreaker". In the comics, [Stormbreaker](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Stormbreaker) is the axe created for and wielded by [Beta Ray Bill](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Beta_Ray_Bill_(Earth-616)) (who gets a [passing reference/easter egg in *Thor Ragnarok*](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/11/02/thor-ragnarok-beta-ray-bill-easter-egg/)).

[image: Stormbreaker]

Comment: Who's that below Groot?

Comment: @JAB One of Thanos' Black Order. I forget which one.

Comment: Unconfirmed, but speculated the last image is fake; Thor has no eye patch, and whilst his body is photorealistic the arm/axe are an illustration (although this *is quite* common on merchandise)...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional [This is not the only bit of IW merch/promo material to be missing the eye patch](https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-art-thor-eye-patch/). Even in the original poster, [he does not appear to have the patch](http://cdn.wegotthiscovered.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/avengers-infinity-war-credit-marvel-studios.jpg). Granted, that was released pre-Ragnarok.

Comment: With the release of *Infinity War*, we now know that it was indeed an axe named Stormbreaker.

Comment: and we also know why Thor does not wear a patch but the story is a little gross if I recall correctly